# Automatically spawns a code and get error

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I used `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` this code in AndroidManifest.xml but wrong line and i tried to change different line and i getting error. If i delete this line, when i run or clean or rebuild, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` this code adding automatically in wrong line. I can't do anythink. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.berkancalikoglu.deadbydaylightguide"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <activity android:name="com.berkancalikoglu.deadbydaylightguide.Main36Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [**`uses-permission`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element) must be above the **application** Tag .
2. You can remove **`uses-sdk`**. Maintain from **`build.gradle`** section.
3. Don't edit **`auto-generate Manifest`** file.

Try with

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Answer (score 1):

You are editting auto-generated manifest. You should edit the one from the sources (in `src` dir), not the generated (in `build` dir).

Answer (score 0):

Google Play uses the  elements declared in your app manifest to filter your app from devices that do not meet its hardware and software feature requirements.

By specifying the features that your application requires, you enable Google Play to present your application only to users whose devices meet the application's feature requirements, rather than presenting it to all users.

For important information about how Google Play uses features as the basis for filtering, please read [Google Play and Feature-Based Filtering](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#market-feature-filtering), below.

> So you ought to define your **user permission out side of
>   `<application>...</application>` tag**.

For example :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        ...

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it under manifest file but not in any tag. Also you should remove uses-sdk tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.berkancalikoglu.deadbydaylightguide"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
```

Kolay gelsin :)